# pass a token to a GET Request xamarin forms

Tags: rest, get, xamarin.forms, access-token

not sure if I am doing this right , passing a Token value and then get some info from a webservice. 
I edited this question , it is passing authentication. I will leave it for future searches.

```
 private async  void Data(string AUTH)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {


 var Tokens = Storage.access.AUTH;  
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AUTH);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AUTH);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
            var response = client.GetAsync("https://any adrees.com").Result;

            string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                var content2 = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mensajes>(content2);



            }
            Debug.WriteLine(content);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what type of token you are refer to, my answer will be based on OAuth access token.

You will need to create a `AuthenticationHeaderValue` and set it into HttpClient's headers.

```
var authHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Storage.accessToken.Token);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeader;
```

Comment: I edited the question. I am passing the  bearer, token . however , I am hardcoding the token value . please see my edited question again. Thanks you for your time